# how to revert changes made by terminal commands?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal

How to revert changes in your project if you have ran the commands on terminal like:

```
rails new store
rails g scaffold product name price:decimal --skip-stylesheets
rake db:migrate
rails g bootstrap:install
rails g bootstrap:themed products -f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible for every command.

For example `rake db:migrate`could be revert with `rake db:rollback`

`rails g scaffold product name price:decimal --skip-stylesheets` could be revert with `rails destroy model product`

`rails new store` with a simple `rm -rf store` (be careful with this one!)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test in the console you can use the `sandbox` parameter for the rails console like so:

```
rails console --sandbox
```

In your case you might just delete everything and start over, but you could do something like

```
rails d scaffold product
rake db:rollback
```

I am not sure if you can do

```
rails d bootstrap:install
rails d bootstrap:themed
```

if not, you can just see which files were created and delete them manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly one solution for undoing the scaffold

```
rails destroy scaffold product
```